# Group by rows of a 2d array by two columns and sum two other columns and sort results

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have a array where I need to group by `parentid` and `time` in reverse order.

```
$result = [
    ['ID' => 1, 'totalsum' => 87898, 'totalsuma' => 1234, 'time' => '2017-01-07', 'parentid' => 'parent1', 'username' => 'user1'],
    ['ID' => 2, 'totalsum' => 61405, 'totalsuma' => 0,    'time' => '2017-01-08', 'parentid' => 'parent2', 'username' => 'user2'],
    ['ID' => 3, 'totalsum' => 53824, 'totalsuma' => 0,    'time' => '2017-01-08', 'parentid' => 'parent1', 'username' => 'user1'],
    ['ID' => 4, 'totalsum' => 9313,  'totalsuma' => 0,    'time' => '2017-01-08', 'parentid' => 'parent2', 'username' => 'user3'],
    ['ID' => 5, 'totalsum' => 6420,  'totalsuma' => 0,    'time' => '2017-01-08', 'parentid' => 'parent1', 'username' => 'user4'],
    ['ID' => 6, 'totalsum' => 5826,  'totalsuma' => 0,    'time' => '2017-01-09', 'parentid' => 'parent2', 'username' => 'user2'],
];
```

First I need to group by `time` in reverse order and then `parentid` to sum up `totalsum` and `totalsuma`

I need the following result in a table like this.

```
totalsum        totalsuma       parentid        time
------------------------------------------------------------
5826            0               parent2         2017-01-09
60244           0               parent1         2017-01-08
70718           0               parent2         2017-01-08
87898           1234            parent1         2017-01-07
```

I could try with following code but not getting expected result, though with some changes I could resolve but with only `time` value not by both `time and parentid`

```
if ( count($result) ) {
    $groups = array();
    $key = 0;
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        $key = $item['time'];
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $groups)) {
            $groups[$key] = array(
                'totalsum' => $item['totalsum'],
                'totalsuma' => $item['totalsuma'],
                'parentid' => $item['parentid'],
                'time' => $item['time'],
            );
        } else {
            $groups[$key]['totalsum'] = $groups[$key]['totalsum'] + $item['totalsum'];
            $groups[$key]['totalsuma'] = $groups[$key]['totalsuma'] + $item['totalsuma'];
            $groups[$key]['time'] = $groups[$key]['time'] + $item['time'];
        }
        $key++;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($groups);
    echo "</pre>";
} else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close in your attempt. Instead of grouping by a single column (time), you will need to group by time and parentid. I recommend a "composite key" -- a string that represents a unique combination of the string values to ensure identifiable uniqueness among each respective group.

As for the sorting, you can sort by time DESC then parentid ASC using `usort()` as demonstrated after the grouping process.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oj4k7))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $compositeKey = $row['time'] . $row['parentid'];
    if (!isset($result[$compositeKey])) {
        unset($row['ID'], $row['username']);
        $result[$compositeKey] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$compositeKey]['totalsum'] += $row['totalsum'];
        $result[$compositeKey]['totalsuma'] += $row['totalsuma'];
    }
}
usort($result, fn($a, $b) => [$b['time'], $a['parentid']] <=> [$a['time'], $b['parentid']]);
var_export($result);
```